# Pyomo hourly optimization for multiple locations: why are all the output variables equal to zero?

Tags: python, set, pyomo, hour, ipopt

## Short Version

I'm developing an optimization algorithm to minimize a cost function. Since I want to apply this function to multiple independent locations, the minimization is applied to the *sum* of the cost functions for all locations (so I don't have to apply an objective function for every location). Furthermore, the cost calculation is *annual* but begins with hourly values; therefore, for each location, one must sum the values for all hours.
The model is detailed below.

My problem is: when I run the program, I only get zero for all variables; naturally this is not the solution I'm looking for, but it shouldn't even be a possible solution - since the objective function is a quotient.
Also, the solver indicates there are 35043 variables + 35041 constraints when I run for a single location, and 175215 variables + 175205 constraints when I try five locations - which seems like way too much; it's really strange to me.

To the best of my knowledge, I've tried everything to write alternative (better and more relaxed) versions of the code: eliminate redundant support variables, convert equality constraints into inequality constraints and convert the objective function from non-linear to quadratic. Nothing seems to change the results.

## Long Version

### Summary

I aim to build an optimization algorithm to find the minimum cost to produce 1 kg of green hydrogen in a given set of suitable locations.

Two power plants may exist in each location - a solar PV park and a wind farm - and an electrolyzer system. The installed capacity of both power plants and the nominal input power of the electrolyzer are the decision variables. That is, I want to know what are the values of these variables that yield the minimum cost, for each location.   For that, I must perform a series of operations for hourly values, to convert electricity into hydrogen, and then evaluate the total production in one year. This is where I think the problem lies - connecting both `sets` of locations and hours.

All parameters described below are the same scalar for every location (and every hour) except for the *capacity factors*, which vary hourly and are indexed to each location.

Since this is a deterministic optimization, in which each location is independent of the adjacent ones, it is possible to proceed with a joint minimization of all suitable locations (the minimization of the sum is equal to the sum of the minimizations).

### Problem Notation

This problem can be formulated mathematically as a non-linear programming problem, using the following model:

#### Model initialization

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
from pyomo.core import AbstractModel
from pyomo.dataportal.DataPortal import DataPortal
from pyomo.environ import *
import pandas as pd
import os
os.environ["octeract_options"] = "num_cores=1"

model = AbstractModel()
data = DataPortal()
```

#### Sets

*Imported from pre-prepared [.csv](https://ibb.co/wSk7x2v) files, available [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlqcYAwzSSIcg6ASeTH7U0EdilM78A?e=V9rwqy)*
**L**: eligible location points
**H**: hours in one year

```
model.L = Set()
data.load(filename='modelL-5.csv', set=model.L)

model.H = Set()
data.load(filename='modelH.csv', set=model.H)
```

#### Parameters

**K_solar**: Solar park total costs
**K_wind**: Wind farm total costs
**K_h2**: Electrolyser total costs

**Pmax_solar**: Solar park maximum installed capacity
**Pmax_wind**: Wind farm maximum installed capacity

**Pden_solar**: Solar park power density
**Pden_wind**: Wind farm power density
**Pden_h2**: Electrolyser power density

**alpha**: Available area in each location

**effi**: Electrolyser efficiency

**Sy**: Production Spread Factor

```
K_solar = 728.5
K_wind = 1559.5
K_h2 = 1063.9

Pmax_solar = 50300
Pmax_wind = 475960

Pden_solar = 0.08268
Pden_wind = 0.78231
Pden_h2 = 0.01172

alpha = 608400

effi = 0.0159

Sy = 11.9
```

*Capacity factors are indexed to each location and each hour; imported from pre-prepared [.csv files](https://ibb.co/QQ60Pzx), available [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlqcYAwzSSIcg6ASeTH7U0EdilM78A?e=V9rwqy)*
**CFsolar**: Solar capacity factor
**CFwind**: Wind capacity factor

```
model.CFsolar = Param(model.L, model.H)
data.load(filename='CF_Solar-5.csv', param=model.CFsolar, format='array')

model.CFwind = Param(model.L, model.H)
data.load(filename='CF_Wind-5.csv', param=model.CFwind, format='array')
```

#### Decision Variables

*(The ones that I really want)*
*Variables that only depend on the location:*
**Psolar**: installed capacity of the solar park
**Pwind**: installed capacity of the wind farm
**Ph2**: electrolyser rated power

```
model.Psolar = Var(model.L, initialize=5000, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, Pmax_solar))
model.Pwind = Var(model.L, initialize=5000, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, Pmax_wind))
model.Ph2 = Var(model.L, initialize=5000, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, Pmax_solar+Pmax_wind))
```

#### Support Variables

*(The ones I don't want, but need to get the decision variables)*
*Variables that depend on the location and hour of the year*
**E_res**: Electricity produced
**E_h2**: Electricity directed to the electrolyser
**E_curt**: Electricity curtailed
**Y_h2**: Hydrogen produced by the electrolyser

```
model.E_res = Var(model.L, model.H, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, Pmax_solar+Pmax_wind))
model.E_h2 = Var(model.L, model.H, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, Pmax_solar+Pmax_wind))
model.E_curt = Var(model.L, model.H, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, Pmax_solar+Pmax_wind))
model.Y_h2 = Var(model.L, model.H, domain=NonNegativeReals)
```

### Mathematical Formulation

#### Constraint Equations

*The hourly production of electricity in each location is equal to the solar/wind installed power on that location times the respective capacity factor (dependent on location and hour)*

```
def RESenergy_production_rule(model, l, h):
    return model.E_res[l, h] == model.Psolar[l] * model.CFsolar[l, h] + model.Pwind[l] * model.CFwind[l, h]
model.RESenergy_production = Constraint(model.L, model.H, rule=RESenergy_production_rule)
```

*For each location and in each hour, this produced electricity can be directed to the electrolyser or be unused (curtailed)*

```
def RESenergy_use_rule(model, l, h):
    return model.E_res[l, h] == model.E_h2[l, h] + model.E_curt[l, h]
model.RESenergy_use = Constraint(model.L, model.H, rule=RESenergy_use_rule)
```

*The hourly amount of electricity that is directed to the electrolyser is always limited by the electrolyser input power*

```
def H2energy_production_rule(model, l, h):
    return model.E_h2[l, h] <= model.Ph2[l]
model.H2energy_production = Constraint(model.L, model.H, rule=H2energy_production_rule)
```

*The hydrogen yield is equal to the electricity that is directed to the electrolyser times an efficiency*

```
def H2hydrogen_production_rule(model, l, h):
    return model.Y_h2[l, h] == model.E_h2[l, h] * effi
model.H2hydrogen_production = Constraint(model.L, model.H, rule=H2hydrogen_production_rule)
```

*In each location, the total installed capacity of both power plants and the electrolyser must not exceed the available area*

```
def power_density_rule(model,l):
    return model.Psolar[l]/Pden_solar + model.Pwind[l]/Pden_wind + model.Ph2[l]/Pden_h2 <= alpha
model.power_density = Constraint(model.L, rule=power_density_rule)
```

#### Objective Function

Minimize the sum of all the points in the set

```
def objective_function(model):
    return sum((K_solar*model.Psolar[l] + K_wind*model.Pwind[l] + K_h2*model.Ph2[l]) / ((sum(model.Y_h2[l,h] for h in model.H))*Sy) for l in model.L)
model.obj = Objective(rule=objective_function, sense=minimize)
```

### Solving the model

*Solving using Octeract-Engine, but should work with any NLP solver (e.g. IPOPT)*

```
instance = model.create_instance(data)
#optimizer=SolverFactory('ipopt')
optimizer = SolverFactory('octeract-engine', executable=r"C:\Program Files\Octeract\bin\octeract-engine.exe")
results = optimizer.solve(instance, tee = True)
```

*Get the status of the results*

```
status = results.solver.status
print("Status:", status)
termination = results.solver.termination_condition
print("Termination:", termination)

model.pprint()
```

### Error messages

For one location, the solver runs for about 1min (for five locations it's almost 10min) and then states:

> EXIT: Maximum CPU time exceeded.
> WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into model=unknown;
> Status: warning
> Termination: maxIterations

Also, for both tests, `model.pprint()` outputs the contents of the model, which are all invariably with *Size=0* and *Not constructed*.

### Export data

*Exporting the decision variables to a CSV; every time, the result is zero.*

```
Psolar=instance.Psolar
Psolar_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=[['id1','id2']])
for index in Psolar:
    Psolar_out.at[index,'id1']=value(Psolar[index])
Psolar_out.to_csv('_psolar.csv')


Pwind=instance.Psolar
Pwind_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=[['id1','id2']])
for index in Pwind:
    Pwind_out.at[index,'id1']=value(Pwind[index])
Pwind_out.to_csv('_pwind.csv')


Ph2=instance.Psolar
Ph2_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=[['id1','id2']])
for index in Ph2:
    Ph2_out.at[index,'id1']=value(Ph2[index])
Ph2_out.to_csv('_ph2.csv')
```

Comment: Do you get null values even when solving for a single location?

Comment: @Haakh yes; either for one location, or five, or anything else, the output is always 0.0 for every variable.  Just tried for a single location again now: everything's zero.

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas/observations that might help:

1. Your variable for "curtailed power" can probably be removed and just make the associated constraints inequalities.  That will remove some seemingly unnecessary (?) variables.  For example if it is something like:

```
Tot_power = Hydrogen_power + curtailed_power
```

to:

```
Tot_power >= Hydrogen Power
```

2. Your model is quite large for a non-linear model.  I just poked around on the data.  solving for (what is it?) 10,000 time periods in a non-linear model is probably too much.  You could either:  make your model linear (good idea) or aggregate to daily or 6-hour blocks, or run your model on different periods if they are independent and compare answers.
3. Make your model linear to start and get it working by removing the division.  See where that gets you.  Linear model should solve almost instantly.
4. There doesn't appear to be any incentive/pressure in your model to make any power.  You are constraining the upper production, but you have no demand signal that I can see and you are minimizing cost, so you might be getting the default solution:  build nothing/do nothing ==> costs are zero.  :)
5. Only inspect data values if you can get a good status out of the solver.  Any other errors/infeasible/timeout/etc. means that the data loaded is junk.
6. You can experiment and make your model linear by changing your objective from a ratio (with division by a variable) to just a penalty for the divisor:

   sum(p_wind + p_solar + p_h2) - w * sum(Y_h2)

where `w` is some reasonable weighing value.  That + some demand signal (or profit) should get the model breathing.  Remember:

```
linear_model_that_works_but_has_some_warts >> broken_model
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.


1. Indeed you are correct; as I state, there are some _support variables_ that I don't really want, so they can be eliminated. I went a step further on what you said and actually eliminated both **E_res** and **E_curt**. The newly updated constraint is as follows (please confirm it's correct):


`def H2energy_production_rule(model, l, h):
    return model.E_h2[l, h] <= model.Psolar[l] * model.CFsolar[l, h] + model.Pwind[l] * model.CFwind[l, h]
model.H2energy_production = Constraint(model.L, model.H, rule=H2energy_production_rule)`

Comment: 2. Also true, and something I've wondered myself too. I'm afraid I cannot aggregate to daily or 6-hour blocks without compromising the accuracy of the results, so the only sensible option would be to convert it to a linear model. Is there any way to do it? I think I've read somewhere you can turn your NLP into Quadratic, but not completely linear :(

Comment: 3. Is there any way you have envisioned converting this non-linear program into a linear one? Please let me know if that is the case.

Comment: 4. You could be right; however, the incentive should come precisely from the non-linearity. The objective function is a division of cost by production; if you build nothing, your cost is zero, but so is your production - so you shouldn't be able to get null values, since that leads to 0/0. Nevertheless, I updated the lower bound of all the decision variables to 5.

Comment: I just run the program a couple of times with these new changes. I got fewer variables and constraints this time (for one location: 17523 variables + 17521 constraints), but similar results. The solver outputs **Restoration phase is called at point that is almost feasible, with constraint violation 4.276904e-19. Abort. Restoration phase in the restoration phase failed. EXIT: Restoration Failed!** Don't really know what that means...

Comment: You are mistaken to rely on "not being 0/0" as a model incentive to produce.  That is just going to lead to odd asymptotic behavior.  Just do 2 things to start:  Put in a demand:  `tot_power[h] >= some_nominal_demand`.  Make your model linear by removing the division by a variable in the OBJ.  Just make it a weighted penalty and subtract it...totally linear.  See my edit above.

Comment: One more thing regarding the size of the problem; all my constraints are linear, and only the objective function is non-linear. I do have to evaluate the constraints for every one of the 8760 time periods, but shouldn't the objective function be evaluated only for every _location_? Especially if I create another constraint to make the sum before the obj. function (simplified): `model.h2sum[l] == sum(model.Y_h2[l,h] for h in model.H)*Sy` and the obj. function becomes (simplified): `sum((K_solar*model.Psolar[l] + K_wind*model.Pwind[l] + K_h2*model.Ph2[l]) / (model.h2sum[l]) for l in model.L)`

Comment: Your understanding of the evaluation of the OBJ is incorrect.  Without getting in to the inner workings of solvers (I'm no expert), it is evaluated an arbitrary number of times.  You have 100K plus variables (hours x locations x variables).  It's not gonna work non-linear....  try my suggestions...

Comment: Indeed, the iterations do seem to fluctuate a lot while solving; I will add a virtual demand as you suggest and run again. Although I'm afraid I still don't really understand how to make the model linear; would you mind elaborating a little more, please?

Comment: this isn't meant to be a chat session... :).  However, the only non-linear element you have in your model is division of one variable by another one in the OBJ.  Division=non-linear.  Remove the division.  I suggest how in the edited solution above.  Do that, try a linear solver.  If there are other non-linearities, the solver will likely barf and point them out to you.

Comment: Sure, you're right. Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try to run the model after making the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The size looks about right from a quick look at your data. Octeract Engine has a state-of-the-art presolver, so it's best to leave it up to the engine to eliminate variables since it will do it in a numerically stable way. The engine may also decide to keep some redundant constraints and variables if it determines that they can be used to tighten the relaxation of the problem, so it's best to focus on the logic in your model and not to worry about redundant information.

I have seen that specific Pyomo message when the solver times out during the presolve phase, and before it gets to branch and bound. This is a Pyomo limitation when a solver times out without producing a `.sol file`, but that's what's actually happening - it's hard to tell without the solver logs, but I assume that you have specified some termination condition for the solver to time out.

If you haven't, the only reason that comes to mind is that the engine detected your problem as convex, passed it to IPOPT, and then IPOPT failed to solve it. This is the intended behaviour in this case since there's nothing more the engine itself can do.

One option you can try is to specify `USE_APPROX_EQUALITY_CONSTRAINTS = true` in the octeract-engine options, which will reformulate your equality constraints. While this is a bad idea in the general case, I added the option because it often helps with large NLPs where IPOPT struggles with feasibility.

You can also try changing the [starting point selection strategy](https://docs.octeract.com/sp1001-starting_point_for_ipopt).

Furthermore, you can control the IPOPT invoked by octeract-engine by adding an `ipopt.opt` options file in your execution directory. This will allow you to control exactly what IPOPT is doing, including changing its constraint violation options.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The model is working much better now; I'll try perfecting it with your suggestions.